# Unable to import oauth-1.0a in Angular 5

Tags: typescript, oauth, angular5

I'm trying to import oauth-1.0a.js file into a service file but it doesn't seems to work. I did `npm install oauth-1.0a --save` and import "OAuth" at the top of the file, here's the file wc.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { crypto } from 'crypto-js';
import { OAuth } from 'oauth-1.0a';

@Injectable()
export class WcService {

  oauth: OAuth;

  constructor() { 
    this.oauth = OAuth({
      consumer: {
        key: 'ck_123',
        secret: 'cs_452'
      },
      signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
      hash_function: function(base_string, key) {
          return crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(crypto.HmacSHA1(base_string, key));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

But webpack failed to compile with this error:

> ERROR in src/app/wc.service.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/wamp/www/pwa-wp/planwize/node_modules/oauth-1.0a/oauth-1.0a"' has
>   no exported member 'OAuth'.

1. The path is correct, as "crypto" is imported fine from "crypto-js".
2. I have notice this two lines in "oauth-1.0a/oauth-1.0a.d.ts": `export as namespace OAuth;` and `export = OAuth;`. So it seems that "OAuth" is an exported member in "/oauth-1.0a"..?

Comment: Sorry no read it wrong try adding `oauth: OAuth;` inside the `constructor` so it looks like this `constructor( oauth: OAuth )`

Comment: You could try using the traditional JS approach, `import OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to:
`import * as OAuth from 'oauth-1.0a';`